# iterating over a 2D array error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having difficulty with a HackerRank Challenge. My code runs for most cases, but fails others.

The challenge is to find the Max Sum in a 2D array in the shape of an hour-glass that spans a 6 x 6 array. With constraints being integer values of -9 to +9.

Example:

`0 2 4 5 1 2
 0 2 3 3 2 0
 1 4 0 8 6 4   With 8 6 4
 0 2 1 4 7 1          7     = 8 + 6 + 4 + 7 + 6 + 2 + 7 = 40
 5 0 3 6 2 7        6 2 7
 6 3 2 2 0 1`

When I run my code with negative integers, I have a return statement of 0.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static int maxSumValue;
    public static int y;
    public static int maxSumHolder;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[][] = new int[6][6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            maxSumHolder = arr[x][y] + arr[x][y + 1] + arr[x][y + 2]
                    + arr[x + 1][y + 1] + arr[x + 2][y] + arr[x + 2][y + 1] + arr[x + 2][y + 2];
            if (maxSumHolder > maxSumValue || maxSumHolder == maxSumValue){
                maxSumValue = maxSumHolder;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxSumValue);
}
}
```

Any suggestions, hints, and/or solutions are welcomed!

Comment: `maxSumValue` is not being initialised so it gets a value of `0` (by default). If all the numbers are negative then no sums will exceed it. You should set it to `-Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were interested in alternative solutions. Here is one that makes heavy use of Java 8 streams, for your interest. It's a lot longer (and less efficient) than your solution but arguably encapsulates the logic rather than having it embedded in the array calculations.

```
class Position {
    public static final int SIZE = 6;
    private final int row;
    private final int col;

    private Position(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public static Stream<Position> all() {
        return IntStream.range(0, SIZE).boxed()
                .flatMap(row -> IntStream.range(0, SIZE)
                        .mapToObj(col -> new Position(row, col)));
    }

    public static Stream<Position> allNonEdge() {
        return all().filter(Position::notOnEdge);
    }

    private boolean notOnEdge() {
        return row > 0 && col > 0 && row < SIZE - 1 || col < SIZE - 1;
    }

    public int shapeSum(int[][] array) {
        return all().filter(this::isInShape)
                .mapToInt(pos -> pos.getVal(array))
                .sum();
    }

    private boolean isInShape(Position other) {
        int rowdiff = Math.abs(this.row - other.row);
        int coldiff = Math.abs(this.col - other.col);
        return rowdiff == 0 && coldiff == 0 || rowdiff == 1 && coldiff <= 1;
    }

    public int getVal(int[][] array) {
        return array[row][col];
    }

    public void setVal(int[][] array, int val) {
        array[row][col] = val;
    }    
}
```

And here is some code showing how it can be used:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] array = new int[Position.SIZE][Position.SIZE];
    Position.all().forEach(pos -> pos.setVal(array, rand.nextInt(100)));
    Position.allNonEdge()
            .mapToInt(pos -> pos.shapeSum(array))
            .max()
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You are correct, it definitely encapsulates the logic on how you would iterate and change rows when going through each integer. BTW, I love your use of lambdas for your solution. I am very wet behind the ears on how to use them, but this is a great example!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be occurring because if negative values are being added, then it'll never be greater than the original value of `maxSumValue`, which starts off as zero (Java will initialize it to zero by default since it was never initialized to anything). A simple fix here is to just take the absolute value of `maxSumHolder` when comparing it to `maxSumValue` so that negative values will be taken into account. This,

```
if (maxSumHolder > maxSumValue || maxSumHolder == maxSumValue)
```

should be changed to

```
if (Math.abs(maxSumHolder) > maxSumValue || Math.abs(maxSumHolder) == maxSumValue)
```

However, if you're objective is not to find the sum with the greatest magnitude and you do feel that a smaller positive sum holds greater weight that a huge negative sum, then my suggestion would be to initialize `maxSumValue` to the smallest possible number Java can hold. Change

```
public static int maxSumValue;
```

to

```
public static int maxSumValue = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why when I was dealing with negative values that I was only returning 0. Establishing the largest negative value as a comparison makes a ton of sense.